# Set the default browser, system-wide, on Manjaro

Tags: browser, manjaro

In Ubuntu I used

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

to set the default internet browser manually.

[image]

In Manjaro I get:

```
sudo: update-alternatives: command not found
```

I have set Firefox as the default in its settings and want it to stay so.

After installing Chromium, the default browser is now Chromium, although I reconfirmed Firefox as such and in Chromnum settings it says: "Chromium cannot determine or set the default browser".

How to make Firefox default browser?

Comment: Does manjaro have the x-www-browser symlink? And to what it links? Also, is update-alternatives available in Manjaro?

Comment: @Braiam - No. And no, not even in AUR.

Comment: If your system doesn't have `x-www-browser`, what is “changing the linked binary” supposed to mean? Are you trying to change the default browser? That depends on the application that launches it — I don't think Manjaro has a system-wide default (and it's more of a user preference anyway). What application are you interested in?

Comment: @Gilles - that phrasing of the title is due to the edit made by [Braiam](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41104/braiam), while I was just asking out of curiosity thinking that the ubuntu option would be available in Manjaro. If not, that's my answer. (Installing Chromium, it took over as default browser. I think I fixed it simply from the FF GUI.)

Comment: @cipricus Oh, I see, sorry. Your original title was [misleading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) too. Once again, I don't think Manjaro has a system-wide or per-user default, so you'll get better help if you mention which applications you use that launch a browser.

Comment: @Gilles - I have now edited the question to fit the new title, which is basically what I want.

Answer (score 27):

For users of i3wm, in addition to editing `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and `~/.i3/config`, you also need to change `$BROWSER` from `~/.profile`, set it to `/usr/bin/chromium`, to prevent browser sessions emerging from the terminal from opening the wrong browser.

Comment: Actually, I find that this is the *only* solution that solved my problem. This *is* a separate answer. For applications that open the default browser (such as Jupyter) changing just the key bindings won't work.

Comment: for me removing the palemoon package was also required `pacman -R palemoon-bin`

Answer (score 20):

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium.desktop
```

Comment: Where `chromium` is whatever you'd type at the command prompt to start your preferred browser. Eg, it could be `google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: Works for voidlinux with i3.

Comment: Does not work on Manjrao I3: `xdg-settings: $BROWSER is set and can't be changed with xdg-settings`, but Anas answer worked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434465/28262

Comment: For Google Chrome, I had to use `xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop`. `xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome-stable` gave a *xdg-settings: invalid application name* error; using the full path for *google-chrome-stable* gave the same error.

Comment: @apaderno yours was the ONLY solution that helped me on LUBUNTU 20.04 with Google Chrome. However, I had to do `unset BROWSER` to remove the` $BROWSER` variable so that the `xdg-settings` command worked.

Answer (score 14):

This question is a bit old, but I would like to register my solution. After struggling with `xdg-settings`, what worked for me was `xdg-mime`.

So, check your default browser with:

```
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
```

And change whatever browser you want to use. Make sure you use the `.desktop` after the browser name.

```
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
```

Then, check again:

```
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
```

Comment: Of course, nothing else worked for me. Do you know in which files this configuration is kept ? For me .config/mimeapps.list contained chrome even before xdg-mime...

Comment: I think mimeapps.list is the default config file for this. Look for this file in other locations. See examples [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications#mimeapps.list)

Comment: Confirmed working on latest install of manjaro when opening webpage links directly from terminal and in intellij.

Comment: This is the best-working answer. I installed brave after having fiddled with mimeapps.list , where I already had set chromium as my default. Brave took over being the default, despite all the entries in mimeapps.list, but this set it back to chromium

Answer (score 6):

Edit your `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and replace references to `firefox.desktop` with `google-chrome.desktop`.

If you use `google-chrome-stable` to launch chrome, use that instead, followed by `.desktop`.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else has the same issue…

Edit your config file:

```
nano ~/.i3/config
```

and change

```
bindsym $mod+F2 exec …
```

to your browser of choice (e.g. `bindsym $mod+F2 exec google-chrome-stable`)
Save and reload your config file (<kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Should be all set…

Comment: This seems overly i3-centric.

Comment: Yes... it was. Now on xfce, which Tom addresses below.

Answer (score 2):

I tried most of the answers in here. This is what I ended up doing

```
sudo pacman -R firefox
```

Just removed firefox. If I install firefox again with `sudo pacman -S firefox` it sets as default again so annoying.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using i3 with Palemoon pre-installed and want to replace it with a cooler browser, like brave:

Please edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and replace references to `Moon.desktop` with `brave.desktop`.

To easily replace all the `Moon` cases to `brave`  in the `mimeapps.list` file with vim, use `:%s/Moon/brave/gc` and answer yes to each case.